# How to use the windows 11 store navigation in uwp/winui3

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store, winui-3, windows-11

I would like to use the navigation used in the new windows 11 store (image below).
But there is no premade control for this style, only the NavigationView.
Did Microsoft not made this public so we need to replicate it our self or am I missing something?

[image: 1]

Comment: Yes, that's a `NavigationView`. And its style should be customized for the Store app. You might need to change the default style by yourself to get such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, they've just used an existing control called Navigationview and modified it because these controls look really similar.

But I don't think they've published their modified control.